# What smooth Git workflow to use to get from a development to a release?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

My question is not very clear (yet) and I may need your feedback to more understand what I am really looking for...

Anyway, I've read quite a lot about `git-flow` and other flows used on Git and I am still divided on how to solve my situation.

I currently have a `master` branch that evolved as both, development and release. This mainly because all the history was imported from our previous SCM. Also we placed a `tag` on each release.

Today we are starting a release-process. With our only master branch, we are forced to freeze the development until the release is done. Alternatively we could:

1. Create a `rc` branch from the `master` on which the hot-fixes are applied. Eventually merge `rc` on a `release` branch then apply a tag to it.
2. Create a `develop` branch from the `master` then use the `master` as the `rc` branch. Eventually apply a `tag` on the `master` and continue with `develop` as the main development branch.

With solution (1), the question of creating the branch on the first release then back merge all the next release into it is open. Also the tags should be moved as well which can be confusing.

With solution (2), the `master` is considered as a release branch not a development branch as it should be.

I am not really convinced by git-flow which adds some complexity. I want the `master` branch to remain the *trunk* of the project, but in this case I don't know which solution is the most adapted.

**Use case:**

I have this git log from which I would like to start a release validation process.

```
* some changes
* v1.1.1 [v1.1.1]
* hotfix
* v1.1 [v1.1]
* merged feature foo into master
* changes
* v1.0 [v1.0]
```

The first solution is to keep `master` the development branch, then create a `release/v1.2rc` branch

```
* v1.2 [v1.2] (release/releases) 
| * merge next feature to master (master)
* | changing version rc to release (release/v1.2rc)
| * merged hotfix
|/|
* | hotfix 
|/
* some changes
* v1.1.1 [v1.1.1]
* hotfix
* v1.1 [v1.1]
* merged feature foo into master
* changes
* v1.0 [v1.0]
```

To keep all the releases into the `release/releases` branch, it would be useful to do the job from the beginning:

```
    * v1.2 [v1.2] (release/releases) 
   /|
  / |
 /* | merge next feature to master (master)
* | | changing version rc to release (release/v1.2rc)
| * | merged hotfix
|/| |
* | | hotfix 
|/ /
* * v1.1.1 [v1.1.1]
*/| some changes
* | v1.1.1
| * v1.1 [v1.1]
*/| hotfix
* | v1.1
* | merged feature foo into master
* | changes
| * v1.0 [v1.0]
*/
* v1.0
```

This allows to do `git log release/releases`

```
* v1.2 [v1.2] (release/releases) 
* v1.1.1 [v1.1.1]
* v1.1 [v1.1]
* v1.0 [v1.0]
```

However by moving the tags and the releases on separate branch we loose visibility on the `master`. Furthermore a bug correction correction on a previous release *i.e.* v1.1.2 is not easy to make and at the end of the day we get a pretty disturbing `release/releases` log:

```
* v1.1.2 hotfix [v1.1.2]
* v1.2 [v1.2] (release/releases) 
* v1.1.1 [v1.1.1]
* v1.1 [v1.1]
* v1.0 [v1.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible option we are using. We create release tags instead of release branches.

```
git checkout master
#make some commits
git tag v1.0.0
git push <remote> v1.0.0
```

now the build server can get the tag v1.0.0

```
mkdir buildspace
cd buildspace
git init
git fetch <remote_url> v1.0.0
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
#run the build job
```

If extra commits are needed for the release, we can fetch and checkout v1.0.0, make the commits, and update the tag v1.0.0 to the new HEAD or just create another tag like v1.0.1 and push it. After the release is done, we can merge the tag to master if necessary. In some cases, the commits for the release are not all needed on the master and we can just apply some of them back to master by `git cherry-pick` or `git rebase`. Meanwhile master does not have to be freezed. We can make other commits on master and push to the remote master, which have nothing to do with the release.